# In how many ways can the miner tunnel from the top left box to the bottom right box of a $4 \times 4$ grid?

Tags: permutations, combinations

A miner is digging a tunnel in a $4$ by $4$ grid. He starts at the top left box and can tunnel only directly down or directly towards his right.  In how many diffrent ways can he reach the bottom right box?

Comment: Whats the position of bottom box.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to solve the problem? Think about how many "steps" the miner needs to take to the right and how many down, and whether the order of these steps matters.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that he can tunnel only directly down or directly right??

Comment: By that i mean that, in the grid he can only move downwards or right wards

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $r$ be the number of steps the miner takes to the right and $d$ the number of steps down, before reaching the bottom right of the box. 
Then $r$ and $d$ will always be equal to $3$. So this problem boils down to find the total number of sequences with length $6$ containing $3$ r's and $3$ d's.

For instance $rrrddd$ is one such sequence.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me a lot, it is the right idea, although the number of times the miner needs to go down and right ways are 3 each, this gives the conclusion of 
6!/(3!*3!) as three downs and three rights are repeated and not distinguished from each other

Answer (score 0):

let us consider it to be a string of length $8$ with $4$ repetitions of $r,d$ so here total ways/ permutations are $\frac{8!}{4!.4!}=\frac{1680}{24}=70$ so thats all total ways are $70$ hope its clear.

Comment: The answer to this question is unfortunately 20..

Comment: Do u get 'all' total ways.

Comment: Yes we get all different ways

Comment: @ArchisWelankar  The miner does not follow the grid lines.  Instead, he moves from the interior of the top left box to the interior of the bottom right box.  Consequently, there are three moves to the right and three downward moves.

Comment: I was suggesting for all and then subtracting other ways . But thats a bit messy i suppose thus answer given by atharva is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

When plotted , you will realize that the miner needs to go 3 down and 3 right
rrrddd , are the given moves , the permutations of these will be the answer.
Given the fact that the permutations need to be different
 in a significant way,
6!/(3!*3!) is the right answer which is 20